# How to make the variable of an if statement dynamic

Tags: c#, if-statement, for-loop

Hi I am trying to loop through a set of int variables and do an if on each one.  I.e.

```
int a0, a1, a2,a3;
for (int I=0; I < 3; I++)
{
    if("a" + I > 10)
    {
        // do something 
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to iterate you need a collection

```
IEnumerable<int> numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 10 };
foreach (var item in numbers)
{
    if(item > 10)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

When you write `"a" + I` all you are doing is create a string that is a concatenation of the two pieces and is not the parameter you defined before

You can then proceed and use linq:

```
 var filtered = numbers.Where(item => item > 10)
```

Comment: Thank you  makes conpleate sense now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array as variable so you can iterate that :

```
        int[] a = new int[3];
        a[0] = 5;
        a[1] = 10;
        a[2] = 15;            
        for (int I = 0; I < 3; I++)
        {
            if (a[I] > 10)
            {
                // do something, example:
                Console.WriteLine(a[I])
            }
        }
```

Result :
15